# Convert data from db to JSON using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, database, mamp

I have already seen many questions but nothing has helped.
I want to convert my data from database (MySQL) to JSON using PHP. This is my PHP code:

**init.php**

```
<?php
$db_name = "webappdb";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "root";
$server_name = "localhost";
$charset= "utf8";

$con = mysqli_connect($charset, $server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db_name);
?>
```

**listViewBooks.php**

```
<?php

include("init.php");

header('Content-Type: application/json');

// get all items from user_info_book table
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `user_info_book`");

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $output[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($output);
echo json_last_error();

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

The error is `0`, so it's nothing.

Comment: no need for $res you are already running the query for $sql

Comment: Also I dont think you can set the charset directly into the connection,you might need to do `$con->set_charset('utf8');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems in your code. For starters, you have this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `user_info_book`");

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

`$sql` is a `mysqli_result` object on success or boolean `false` on failure. Here, it's false because you didn't pass the database link (`$con`). See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). You shouldn't, don't need to, and *can't* store the result of `mysqli_query` in a variable (`$sql`) and then pass that variable in another call to `mysqli_query`. Just do:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user_info_book`";

$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Also, you initialize one array, then add to another:

```
$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $output[] = $row;
}
```

Perhaps you mean to do `$output = array();`?

You would benefit from using an IDE like PHPStorm.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm new in php. Thank you Ed.

Comment: @Carlo Glad to help out!

Answer (score 0):

So you execute a query and assign the result to `$sql`:

```
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `user_info_book`");
```

But then you query again and use the `$sql` result as if it were a string:

```
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Probably more what you were thinking:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user_info_book`";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

You should use error reporting when developing:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm new in php. Thank you AbraCadaver.

Answer (score 0):

You code is bad:

```
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `user_info_book`");
                    ^---missing DB handle
 ^---query result handle
```

So `$sql` becomes boolean `false` for failure, because you didn't call the query function correctly.

You then blindly use this boolean false as if it was a query string:

```
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                           ^---boolean false, due to previous errors
```

So basically, you assumed your code was perfect, and could never ever possibly have any problems, so failed to add any error handling. Since you have no error handling, you utterly ignored the errors that DID occur.

Never **EVER** assume success - this code is a perfect example of WHY. Your sql is syntactically perfect, yet it failed because you didn't call the query function properly.

Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm new in php. Thank you Marc.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize an array called `$result` but try to use an array with the `$output` identifier which has not been initialized, PHP will not auto-initialize an array variable for you. That is where one error comes from.

The second error I noticed is:

```
mysqli_query("SQL")
```

You forgot to pass in the database connection resource as it should be:

```
mysqli(db_connection, sql_query)
```

Fix those then if you need more assistance, comment below.

Have a good day.